# Can someone please explain this code to me? I have having trouble understanding how to create a main method that calls the boolean(Java)

Tags: arrays, boolean

```
 public class array{
    public boolean isSorted (int[] a){
       int temp = a[0];
       for (int i=1; i < a.length; i++) {
           if (temp < a[i])
           temp = a[i];
       else
           return false;
       }
       return true;
  }
}
```

To call the code I tried doing something like this

```
    public class first {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        WhileLoop is = new WhileLoop();
        is.isSorted();
    }
```

if someone could explain how the code with the array works, and then also how to call it properly as i'm not sure what to put in the parameter for isSorted that would be so helpful! thanks

Comment: Questions about basic programming should be tagged with a specific programming language.  (It **looks** like Java with errors  in it... but it could be some other language with different errors in it.  You need to **tell** us.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what programming language you're using, providing details like that can help guide answers a lot.

The way you have that code laid out, `isSorted` is method that can be executed on an instance of a class of type `array`.

Incidentally, it has no bearing on the actual instance, which makes the code a little bizarre, or perhaps you're using a language where all methods can be addressed as static methods.

Without altering the `array` code, you'd probably want to do something like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
  array myArrayInstance = new array();
  int[] theActualIntArray = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 6, 7 };
  bool isSortedResult = myArrayInstance.isSorted(theActualIntArray);
}
```

If you can change the `array` class to have `isSorted` be a static method, you can simplify the code as follows:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] theActualIntArray = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 6, 7 };
  bool isSortedResult = array.isSorted(theActualIntArray);
}
```

since static methods are members of the class itself and not an instance, you wouldn't actually need an instance of `array` new'd up to use the method.

Comment: Sorry about that it is in java, I will in the future be sure to put it in the tags or title!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @BryanHeddle, my answer should hold true for java.  I edited to show an example of how you could modify the `array` class to make it make a little more sense.

Answer (score 0):

To be fair, you'll need to look up data types, function returns, array sort algorithms (bubblesort as an example).

To explain it simply: the function returns true if the array that is passed is sorted, false otherwise. The parameter it needs is an array. An array is a sort of a "list" of items (some languages call it a "vector" which is not the same as the "vector" in physics or 2D/3D math space). Having said that, you need to initialize an array, then pass it along the function.

An example is

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    array arraySorter = new array();
    int[] myArray = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 6, 7 };
    bool isSorted = arraySorter.isSorted(myArray);
    System.out.println( "Is it sorted? " + isSorted.toString() );
}
```

I am curios what this `WhileLoop is = new WhileLoop();` is. Where did you copy it from and why do you call is sorted on it?

But as I said, without the basics, it will be hard for you to understand the code. Learning programming isn't just blindly copy-pasting code and "seeing what it does". You must first study a language, it's paradigms (believe it or not, they are important), its syntax, its data types, its function types (yes, some languages have more than one function type and their difference isn't simply in the params they have or return type), whether it supports OOP, polymorphism, whether it's interpreted, compiled, low-level and so much more.

Now, regarding Stack Overflow, you should also mark the language it represents. Check the rules of the site please. You also need to properly ask the question as your code seems to have a lot of issues. Asking us to arrange code that not even you know what it does is not constructive.

Comment: Ahh, sorry about that, the while loop is the original name of the Array class. This was because I deleted the code from one class and pasted the new code in it. I renamed it array when posting because its not a while loop, but forgot to change the other part to array as well. thank you for the advice, i have a final coming up and am studying although arrays is something I failed to fully understand and am now going over. I understood what the code does but was having trouble understanding the way to use arrays properly. Now I ask, what is the toString referencing in your code?

Comment: `println()` displays the result to stdout (in this case, the result of the sort). It's either `true` or `false` so I made it output whther it's either. Booleans are conditionals, their values can't be "displayed", therefore a string conversion is necessary. Look up arrays in C, C# or Java, the concept is the same. What the function does is related to sorting, I gave you an algorithm as example (regardless of whether it is the same or not). You'll find tons of sites explaining array sorting and BubbleSort is the most common.